# Server.Transfer does not work?

Tags: asp.net

I want to redirect to another page using Server.Transfer and I have this simple code:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
   {
     try
     {
       Server.Transfer("AnotherPage.aspx");
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {                                
       throw ;
     }
    }
```

But I'm getting an error: "Error executing child request for AnotherPage.aspx.". Could not find the solution on the net.

Just to mention, Response.Redirect works flawlessly.

Comment: What happens when you go to AnotherPage.aspx in the browser? Does it work? Is it in the same folder/path ?

Comment: Are you actually just trying to redirect the user to the new page? If so, use Response.Redirect() instead of Server.Transfer(). If there are errors on AnotherPage.aspx, they will become clear after you use Response.Redirect() *or* navigate to AnotherPage.aspx directly from the browser.

Comment: What happens when you remove the try/catch block? There's no sense in eating exceptions here, then asking what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely caused by something in AnotherPage.aspx. You may want to insert a `try... catch` handler in AnotherPage.aspx's Load event.